# error: expected primary-expression before string

Tags: c++

I would like to read a file and put the number of times the word appears in a std::map. So I made the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

    int main() {
    std::map<std::string, unsigned> M;
    std::ifstream declaration("declaration.txt");
    while(declaration >> std::string s){
        M[s]=0;
    }
    while(declaration >> std::string s){
        M[s]=M[s]+1;
    }
    declaration.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the following error messages:

```
text_analyse.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
text_analyse.cpp:8:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘s’
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
                                   ^
text_analyse.cpp:8:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s’
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
       ~                          ^~
                                  )
text_analyse.cpp:8:35: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
                                   ^
text_analyse.cpp:11:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘s’
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
                                   ^
text_analyse.cpp:11:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s’
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
       ~                          ^~
                                  )
text_analyse.cpp:11:35: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
  while(declaration >> std::string s){
                                   ^
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [ask]. We're an english only platform so please translate your question to english.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not in English.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string s` is not a valid expression, it is a *statement*.
Declare the string outside the loop instead:

```
std::string s;
while(declaration >> s){
    M[s]=0;
}
```